# Google sheets - Extract numbers with their units of measurment seperated by a blank space e.g "20 km"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script for a custom function that extracts numbers with their units of measurment:

```js
/**
 * @customfunction
 */
function EXTRACTMEASUREMENT(input) {
  // match all words which starts with a number
  var result = input.match(/\d+[a-zA-Zα-ωΑ-Ω]+\S*/g)
  // combine array into a string separated with spaces
  result = result.join(' ');
  // Remove special characters(except whitespace) in the string
  result = result.replace(/[^a-zA-Zα-ωΑ-Ω0-9\s]/g, '')
  return result;
}
```

For example, i have a text in H42 and i put the function in I42. It works like that:

[image]

[image: output]

But the thing is that, if I put in H42 a number but followed by a space and then the unit of measurment, the function doesnt detect it and as a result, it doenst even extract it. See example:

[image]

As you can see, the "12 kg" and the "1 L" both have a blank space between. So the function only extracts "50gr" which isnt seperated by a blank space.

What can I do so the custom function returns the numbers with their units of measurment even if they are seperated by a blank space?
I want it to return

> 12kg 1L 50gr

just like the 2nd attached image.

I am just a begginer in these so I don't know how to write code. It would be really helpful if you could make the proper modifications to my script and then paste it in the answers.

Comment: No, in fact I posted this question

Comment: In my previous proposal, I have already taken the case with a blank separator. Try the answer I have provided hereafter.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=arrayformula(substitute(transpose(query(flatten(split(
REGEXREPLACE(A1,"([0-9.,/]+[ ]{0,1}[a-zA-Z1-3/.\-""]+)","♣♦$1♣")
,"♣")),"select * where Col1 like '♦%' ")),"♦",""))
```

or with result in one cell

```
=substitute(textjoin(" - ",true,query(flatten(split(
REGEXREPLACE(A1,"([0-9.,/]+[ ]{0,1}[a-zA-Z1-3/.\-""]+)","♣♦$1♣")
,"♣")),"select * where Col1 like '♦%' ")),"♦","")
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly. Only problem is that if in a cell i have: "The 2 cars have speed 400km/h" the function returns "2 cars 400km/h" and i only want the "400km/h". Is this possible?

Comment: it will be difficult even with other answers because when you type `2 cars` the formula understand that the value is `2` then a blank and then unit ... `cars`! and we can't limit the number of characters of cars because you could have units such as Mbps, or other unit may be longer! If you omit the blank there is not such a case but you can't fetch the value and the unit! The only way is to declare which units have to be taken into acount and so prevent from units like ... cars!

Comment: and sometimes, `cars` can be considered as a unit in the sentence `to tranposrt a football team, we will need 3 cars`!